# Help understanding 普通に戻ったということは、そういうことなのだろう

Tags: grammar, meaning

How do I interpret the そういうことなのだろう in 普通に戻ったということは、そういうことなのだろう?

「安心しろ。人の触れられたくない領域に、不用意に近付こうとはしない。キミにとって、とても繊細な問題だっただろうからな」

「……助かります」

「普通に戻ったということは、**そういうことなのだろう**。色々思うところもあるかもしれないが、キミにとっても、重い選択だったろうな」

I understand the general grammar pattern e.g. in the below the meaning is clear

当院は屋久島唯一の病院であり、入院施設をもつ唯一の医療機関です。
島に６つある診療所とともに、屋久島に住む人・訪れる人の命を守っています。 島は台風などで簡単に孤立し、船も飛行機も止まります。
島で生きるということはそういうことです。

However, in the example in the original question the meaning is not so clear.

The context of 普通に戻った is referring to one of the speakers relationships with someone who asked him out but he rejected (and based on the way they are interacting the other speaker also inferred this).

Answer (score 1):

> 普通に戻ったということは、そういうことなのだろう。
> If she came back to normal, it means...you know what I mean.

This そういうこと refers to "*that* certain fact"; some (usually undesirable) fact the speaker doesn't want to directly mention. Depending on the broader context, そういうこと may actually imply キミのことが好きではなかった, 無理をしている, 覚えていない or anything.